# Turn off localization in ubuntu

Tags: keyboard-layout, localization, preinstallation

Okay so when I install Ubuntu and I set my timezone to Belgrade parts of the interface are in Serbian, Cyrillic. That annoys the hell out of me. Some programs are entierly in Serbian even though I installed with English keyboard US layout etc. No where in the install process did I pick Serbian for anything.

Once I install Ubuntu the name of months, days and some programs is, like I said, in Serbian. So I go to language support and text entry and set everything to English there but I see no changes whatsoever. Anyone has any idea on how to fix this? Preferably before I install the system? Some hidden config during the installation or something...

Whose stupid idea was it anyway to automatically translate half of the interface depending on your timezone anyway -.- Do you guys think I should maybe raise a ticket on launchpad?